# call a php variable in createmarker function

Tags: javascript, php, google-maps-api-3

I'm parsing with `php` an `xml` file and i'm trying to put a marker in every `$item`.
The  error i'm getting is : **'Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected string'** in these lines

```
    function createMarker( '<?php echo $item['temp']; ?>',latlng,cold ) {
var marker = createMarker( '<?php echo $item['temp']; ?>',latlng,cold );
```

Here is my code

```
    function initialize() {
      var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 6,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng( 38.822590,24.653320 )
      };
      var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),mapOptions);
            <?php foreach ( $item_array as $item ) : ?>
            var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(<?php echo $item['glat']; ?>),
                                                parseFloat(<?php echo $item['glon']; ?>));
            if ( '<?php echo $item["temp"] ?>' >= "18 °C" ) {
                alert('<?php  echo $item["temp"]; ?>');
                 var marker = createMarker( '<?php echo $item['temp']; ?>',latlng,cold );
            }
            <?php endforeach; ?>

            var cold  = 'weather_icons/pagetos2.png';
            function createMarker( '<?php echo $item['temp']; ?>',latlng,cold ) {
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: latlng,
                map: map,
                icon: cold
                });
                return marker;
            }
    }
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Any ideas how i'm gonna have a succesfull call in createMarker function?

Comment: More importantly, What does the *produced* JavaScript from those two lines look like?

Comment: You can store that value in to cookie or html hidden input then it will be easy for you to compare that !!

Comment: You are using the same string `'<?php echo $item['temp']; ?>'` in function definition (wrong) and function call. So what is the first function parameter and what is it used for?

Comment: @Anto Jurkovic. The first function parameter contains the child element: temp which contains the temprature of every item( which is the parent element of the temp )in the xml.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove first parameter of function createMarker and it will work perfectly.

```
function initialize() {
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 6,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng( 38.822590,24.653320 )
  };
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),mapOptions);
        <?php foreach ( $item_array as $item ) : ?>
        var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(<?php echo $item['glat']; ?>),
                                            parseFloat(<?php echo $item['glon']; ?>));
        if ( '<?php echo $item["temp"] ?>' >= "18 °C" ) {
            alert('<?php  echo $item["temp"]; ?>');
             var marker = createMarker(latlng,cold );
        }
        <?php endforeach; ?>

        var cold  = 'weather_icons/pagetos2.png';
        function createMarker( latlng,cold ) {
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: latlng,
            map: map,
            icon: cold
            });
            return marker;
        }
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Comment: works fine with your idea :DYou had a clever thought

Answer (score 0):

Wrong function definition

```
function createMarker( '<?php echo $item['temp']; ?>',latlng,cold )
...
```

produce the error message:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected string
```

You have to change a function definition to something like

```
   function createMarker( inputParameter, latlng, cold ) {
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: latlng,
            map: map,
            icon: cold
            });
            return marker;
   }
```